# Why might Node be unable to read multiple upper case files in a Windows directory?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems

I have a problem related to a software development library called [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/), but seems to actually be an issue with Windows (specifically, reading files from a drive).

What's interesting is that the problem happens on one drive (C:) but not my 2nd drive (D:), which indicates it's a problem with my Windows config (rather than the software library).

The issue is that the library can read lower case files just fine:

- `foo.ts`
- `bar.ts`

But when it comes to files with upper case chars:

- `Foo.ts`
- `Bar.ts`

It's only able to read one of the files.

Related bug report: [Bug: AST is undefined on Windows when more than one file with upper-case char in filename](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/8267)

I thought perhaps it might be related to a problem with Windows case sensitivity, so I tried disabling it but that didn't make a difference.

```
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo . disable
```

I was about to format my computer, but thought: What if it works on D instead of C?

Works fine on C, but not on D drive.

What could cause this?

Comment: Windows case sensitivity is one thing. Wonder if there is a Node subsystem that is case sensitive?

Comment: I think the hard drive must have been corrupt. `chkdsk` didn't show any errors, but when I was copying my projects from C to D drive, I got a ton of read errors.

Comment: Windows is case-insensitive when reading by default, but does pass correct case to programs. It looks like eslint can have a `useCaseSensitiveFileNames` setting on a per-folder basis, like in https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4680 . But yeah if you get read errors when copying, it may not be eslint's fault